# getBaseContext() = error with Fragments

Tags: android, listview, fragment

**EDIT:    I managed to get it working, thank you for helping!**

I'm trying to follow a guide, but even when I changed almost all the code to the same as the guide I'm still getting error and crashes. The app chrashes when I launch it.

This was my guide: [ListView with images and text](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/listview-with-images-and-text-using-simple-adapter-in-android/)

Comment: What about getApplicationContext() ? Or Activity's Context? And which error are you getting?

Comment: With "getApplicationContext()" I get the error: "The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type MyFragment1"

Comment: can you show your whole `Activity` where you define your `StringArrayAdapter` ?

Comment: I have added the Activity

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type Fragment1UG Fragment1UG.java /NewGames/src/com/jg/newgames line 71 Java Problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `Context` from `Fragment` in Android you should first get the context of your `Activity` which holds your current `Fragment`. So this line

```
StringArrayAdapter ad = new StringArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), aList, R.layout.list_design, from, to);
```

should be :

```
StringArrayAdapter ad = new StringArrayAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), aList, R.layout.list_design, from, to);
```

Check if this is your problem, if not just post the stack trace which you are getting running that code.

**Edit:**

Seeing the code of your Adapter I can see that initialisation of it in your `Activity` is incorrect. It should be :

```
StringArrayAdapter ad = new StringArrayAdapter(mMyStringArray, getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

where `mMyStringArray` is the array of string which you want to show, for example: `TitleList` depending on your code.

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
The constructor StringArrayAdapter(Context, List<HashMap<String,String>>, int, String[], int[]) is undefined Fragment1UG.java /NewGames/src/com/jg/newgames line 71 Java Problem

Comment: How do I post the stack trace?

Comment: Is it giving you an error before even building/running your app on device or your app is crashing after successful build?

Comment: Yes ////////// (sorry, can't just type "yes")   :)

Comment: So post it's code in your question. As I can guess, you are not setting the right variables in your adapter's constructor.